# Add additional property to products field call Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I need to add an additional url parameter (which is dynamic and not fixed) to the fields calls that happen on the PDP page. I have tried extending the the product service but that doesnt fire any of my overide functions.

I have now ended up implementing the product adapter so I just want to confirm this is 100% correct.

```
export class MyProductAdapter implements ProductAdapter {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add a (fixed) value in your fields call you can override the default call and add your missing value. Create a file *yourOccProductDetails.config.ts*

```
export const yourOccProductDetailsConfig: OccConfig = {
  backend: {
    occ: {
      endpoints: {
        product: {
          details: 'products/${productCode}?fields=averageRating,stock(DEFAULT),description,availableForPickup,code,url,price(DEFAULT),numberOfReviews,manufacturer,categories(FULL),priceRange,multidimensional,tags,images(FULL),yourParam',
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

And in your module add the config to your providers array

```
import { yourOccProductDetailsConfig } from './yourOccProductDetails.config'

@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [YourProductDetailsComponent],
  exports: [YourProductDetailsComponent],
  providers: [provideConfig(yourOccProductDetailsConfig)],
})
export class YourProductDetailsModule {}
```

Comment: Its not a fixed value its a dynamic variable for the store code.

Comment: Ok, then you should extend or create an adapter and add your url params in the `buildUrl` method of the `OccEndpointsService`.

Comment: I added a snippet above. I didnt know if I need to use the OCC adapter or directly implement the productAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation part for a problem you have faced:
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/#configuring-endpoints

Comment: This wont work we tried but I just ended up implementing the product adapter